Manifolds, perimeter and volume
The Bergman metric $ g_{i\bar{\jmath}}(z) $ is defined by
$$
   g_{i \bar{j}}(z) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_i \, \partial \overline{z_j}} \log K(z, z)
   $$
which gives the components of the metric tensor.
In the unit ball $ \mathbb{B}_n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, this can be computed explicitly as:
$$
   g_{i \bar{j}}(z) = \frac{(1 - | z |^2) \delta_{ij} + z_i\overline{z_j} }{(1 - | z |^2)^2}.
   $$
In terms of the infinitesimal distance, the Bergman metric in $ \mathbb{B}_n $ defines a line element $ ds$ by
$$
   ds^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^n g_{i \bar{j}}(z) \, dz_i \, d\overline{z_j}.
   $$
We denote by $d  \tau $ the hyperbolic volume measure with respect to the Bergman metric on  $\mathbb{B}_n$, that is,
$$d  \tau (z)=\frac{d v(z)}{(1-\vert z\vert^2)^{n+1}}.$$
A set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{B}_n$ has finite Bergman measure if  $$\tau(\Omega):=\int_{\Omega}d \tau(z)<\infty.$$ If $S=\partial \Omega\subset \mathbb{B}$ is smooth hypersurface, then its associated $2n-1$ measure is denoted by $ \sigma$.
My question is, if $S=\partial \Omega=\{z\in \mathbb{B}, u(z)=r\}$ for some smooth real function $u$, how to  express $d\sigma(z)$ as a function of $u$ for $z\in S$.

What do you mean by "associated"? Are you restricting the Bergman metric to $S$ and then computing the measure?

&Moishe Kohan. Yes
